# Opening files in Xcode editing pane

Tags: xcode

When I first started to work with Xcode, single clicking on a file name in the Groups&Files pane would open that file up for editing in the embedded editing pane. Double clicking the file would open it up in a new window for editing.

Now, single clicking the file does nothing. Double clicking the file will open it up in a new window as before.

How can I set xcode to open up the file in the embedded editing pane by single clicking the file name in the Groups&Files pane?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 3.x, make sure you're using the Default or All-in-one layout--not Condensed.  If the editor pane is not visible, it might be shrunk down to the bottom of the window.  Look for a small gray dot at the bottom and double-click it.  The editor pane should then expand up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the default layout, and the editor pane is visible. However if I single click on a file name in the Group&Files pane, the file does not appear in the embedded editor pane.